# Footnotes in LaTeX are making odd spaces

Tags: footnotes, url

I have to write a paper and I should use footnotes, some footnotes are acting weird and having too many spaces for no obvious reason. This is my code:

```
%******************************************************************************
% Authors should submit papers according to this format.
% LaTeX is a high-quality typesetting system. If you want to know more about LaTeX, please visit http://www.latex-project.org/
%******************************************************************************
%%***************************************************************
\documentclass[twoside,10.5pt]{article}%                         *
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%                                           *
\usepackage{pifont}%                                             *
%\usepackage{url}%                                                *
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}%                                            *
\usepackage{amsthm}%                                             *
\usepackage{txfonts}%                                            *
\usepackage{geometry}%                                           *
\usepackage{latexsym}%                                           *
\usepackage{amssymb}%                                            *
\usepackage{graphicx}%                                           *
\usepackage{geometry}%                                           *
\usepackage{xcolor} %                                            *Please do not change any words here.
\geometry{paperheight=28.5cm,paperwidth=21cm,top=2.5cm,%         *
bottom=2.6cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,headheight=0.8cm,%             *
headsep=0.9cm,textheight=20cm,footskip=1cm}%                   *
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \setlength{\parskip}{5pt}%           *
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}%                            *                                                        *
%%***************************************************************
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%================TITLE===========================================
\begin{center}
{\LARGE{ report}}\\[20pt]
\end{center}

\emph{Past}

 a lot of text \footnote{Barnett, W., \& Han, A, "Facebook in 2011", Case. No. E-406, May 12, 2011, pp. 1-28.}.\\
 a lot of text\footnote{Thompson, N., \& FRED Vogelstein, F., INSIDE THE TWO YEARS THAT SHOOK FACEBOOK—AND THE WORLD, wired.com, \url{www.wired.com/story/inside-facebook-mark-zuckerberg-2-years-of-hell/} , Retrieved May 30, 2018.}

\bigskip

\emph{Present}

 a lot of text\footnote{Rizzo, S., \& Kelly, M., Fact-checking Mark Zuckerberg's testimony on Facebook and data collection., washingtonpost.com, \url{www.washingtonpost.com/news/fact-checker/wp/2018/04/13/fact-checking-mark-zuckerbergs-testimony-on-facebook-and-data-collection}, Retrieved May 30, 2018.}



\end{document}
```

I get the following footnotes:

[image]

The last one, te one starting with *Rizzo* is especially doing so and I can't see why, I've also tried enabling/disabling the package `url` but it didn't help. I have to use this layout so i can't change that to solve the issue, can someone take a look and tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`

Comment: @Johannes_B That decreased the white space but it's still there.

Comment: But that is just because TeX can't find a good hyphenation point in `washingtonpost.com` other than `washington-post.com`

Comment: @moewe So there's no way to get around it?

Comment: @moewe I think this is because of the url. If you keep `post.com` on the previous line, the word `facebook-` from the third line will go to the second, but it does not fit.

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji well, you can do `\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{7pt}{8.4pt}\selectfont}` in the preamble, but don't forget to give a magnifying glass to the reader.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Indeed, it is not exclusively the `washingtonpost.com`. Line breaking is complicated and the entire paragraph is involved in breaking decisions. So it is more a combination of all factors.

Comment: It might be time for `\raggedright` or `ragged2e`'s `\RaggedRight` then.

Comment: Or, you do it in entirely different way: put all those news sites to the bibliography. I think this is the best solution possible.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman But of course the same situation might arise in the bibliography. Line breaking is hard and line breaking of URLs is even more complex so something like this can always happen, especially with bibliography(-like) text.

Comment: @moewe but you can typeset bibliography with `\RaggedRight` which, I think, is better than ragged footnotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be use this commande befor begin document

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother
```

you found below the source code

```
    %******************************************************************************
% Authors should submit papers according to this format.
% LaTeX is a high-quality typesetting system. If you want to know more about LaTeX, please visit http://www.latex-project.org/
%******************************************************************************
%%***************************************************************
\documentclass[twoside,10.5pt]{article}%                         *
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%                                           *
\usepackage{pifont}%                                             *
%\usepackage{url}%                                                *
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}%                                            *
\usepackage{amsthm}%                                             *
\usepackage{txfonts}%                                            *
\usepackage{geometry}%                                           *
\usepackage{latexsym}%                                           *
\usepackage{amssymb}%                                            *
\usepackage{graphicx}%                                           *
\usepackage{geometry}%                                           *
\usepackage{xcolor} %                                            *Please do not change any words here.
\geometry{paperheight=28.5cm,paperwidth=21cm,top=2.5cm,%         *
bottom=2.6cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,headheight=0.8cm,%             *
headsep=0.9cm,textheight=20cm,footskip=1cm}%                   *
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \setlength{\parskip}{5pt}%           *
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}%                            *                                                        *
%%***************************************************************
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%================TITLE===========================================
\begin{center}
{\LARGE{ report}}\\[20pt]
\end{center}

\emph{Past}

 a lot of text \footnote{Barnett, W., \& Han, A, "Facebook in 2011", Case. No. E-406, May 12, 2011, pp. 1-28.}.\\
 a lot of text\footnote{Thompson, N., \& FRED Vogelstein, F., INSIDE THE TWO YEARS THAT SHOOK FACEBOOK—AND THE WORLD, wired.com, \url{www.wired.com/story/inside-facebook-mark-zuckerberg-2-years-of-hell/} , Retrieved May 30, 2018.}

\bigskip

\emph{Present}

 a lot of text\footnote{Rizzo, S., \& Kelly, M., Fact-checking Mark Zuckerberg's testimony on Facebook and data collection., washingtonpost.com, \url{www.washingtonpost.com/news/fact-checker/wp/2018/04/13/fact-checking-mark-zuckerbergs-testimony-on-facebook-and-data-collection}, Retrieved May 30, 2018. }



\end{document}
```

compilation result : 
[image]

If you want to force the first text of the footnote. You can use dolar expression like this :

```
 a lot of text\footnote{$\text{Rizzo, S., \& Kelly, M., Fact-checking Mark Zuckerberg's testimony on Facebook and data collection., washingtonpost.com,}$ \url{www.washingtonpost.com/news/fact-checker/wp/2018/04/13/fact-checking-mark-zuckerbergs-testimony-on-facebook-and-data-collection}, Retrieved May 30, 2018. }
```

Result :

[image]

Or using the href{}{} like this :

```
\footnote{Rizzo, S., \& Kelly, M., Fact-checking Mark Zuckerberg's testimony on Facebook and data collection., washingtonpost.com, \href{www.washingtonpost.com/news/fact-checker/wp/2018/04/13/fact-checking-mark-zuckerbergs-testimony-on-facebook-and-data-collection}{www.washingtonpost.com/..../fact-checking-mark-zuckerbergs-testimony-on-facebook-and-data-collection}, Retrieved May 30, 2018.}
```

[image]

Best wishes 
Abdelkarim